# Find expressions, in terms of m and n, for the roots of the equation: (3m-x)/(x+n)=2(x+m)/(x-n)

Tags: roots, quadratics

Find expressions, in terms of m and n, for the roots of the equation: (3m-x)÷(x+n)=2(x+m)÷(x-n)

$\frac{3m-x}{x+n} = $$\frac{2(x+m)}{x-n}$

Answer: $\frac{-(n-m)±\sqrt{\mathstrut (n-m)^2-60nm}} 2$

I tried doing it like an almost identical question before, but the method is not working for this question or I'm doing it wrong. my answers keep being some version of this:

$-3x^2-x(n-m)+mn$ 
Then I tried to use the quadratic formula on it, but it never got to the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You simplified incorrectly. It should be:

$$(3m-x)(x-n) = 2(x+n)(x+m)$$
$$3mx-3mn-x^2+xn = 2x^2+2mx+2xn+2mn$$
$$-3x^2+mx-nx-\color{red}{5mn}=0$$

Comment: but the answer is still wrong... because when you input into the quadratic equation it doesn't give the same a value and c value as the answer above

Comment: How about you show all your steps? It's hard to figure out where exactly you went wrong.

Comment: I suspect the answer is wrong. According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+in+-3x%5E2%2B%28m-n%29x-5mn%3D0+), the denominator should be $6$ instead of $2$.

Comment: Hi, that's exactly what we got for one of the several times where we tried to work it out, but that's not what the answer book says :(. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The most likely answer is the answer book is wrong :( I will try to use Wolfram Alpha to verify the solution, so you can go take a rest first.

Comment: The solution is verified! Wolfram Alpha gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=value+of+%283m-x%29%28x-n%29+-+%28x%2Bn%29%282%28x%2Bm%29%29+when+x+%3D+1%2F6%28-%28n-m%29+%2B+sqrt%28%28n-m%29%5E2-60nm%29%29) and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=value+of+%283m-x%29%28x-n%29+-+%28x%2Bn%29%282%28x%2Bm%29%29+when+x+%3D+1%2F6%28-%28n-m%29+-+sqrt%28%28n-m%29%5E2-60nm%29%29) which both equal to $0$, which shows that the correct answer is indeed not the one in your textbook.